# Active record import with Nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, roo

I am trying to import bulk of records related to the user using activerecord-import gem. Here Role has the has and belongs to many relationship with the user. While importing user data are imported successfully. But role_ids are not imported..

I have tried by getting valid data mail ids and find users from that valid mail ids and update role ids.. It got success.. I need to know some other methods available using active record import.

user params:-

```
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :first_name, :last_name, role_ids: [])
  end
```

import method:-

```
  def import(import)
    valid_rows = []
    all_roles = {}
    file = Paperclip.io_adapters.for(self.file).read
    Role.all.select(:id, :name).map { |role| all_roles[role.name.gsub(/[^A-Za-z]/, '').downcase] = role.id }

    CSV.parse(file, headers: true, skip_blanks: true, header_converters: ->(header) { header.strip }, converters: ->(data) { data ? data.strip : nil }).each do |row|
      user_role_name = (row['roles'].gsub(/[^A-Za-z]/, '').downcase || [])
      role_ids = [all_roles[user_role_name]] || []
      attributes = { first_name: row['first_name'], last_name: row['last_name'], email: row['email'], role_ids: role_ids}
      row = User.new(attributes)
      if User.new(attributes).valid?
        valid_rows << row
    end

    User.import valid_rows

  end
```

Can someone please explain how to import roles ids with user data while importing!!

Comment: Debug the value of `row`? You have too much things in that method that's difficult to follow without having to scroll. Maybe something is going bad at this point: `all_roles` (or before).

Answer (score 0):

To import multiple records, that accepts nested attributes, we need to add `recursive: true`, thus while importing:

`User.import valid_rows, recursive: true`.